# How to make a SSL connection (iphone)

Tags: iphone, security, ssl, connection

i am making an app in which there is a need of money transaction...

for this i have to send SOAP xml to server but in secure way....

i have been told that i have to create SSL connection first and then send that soap message.....

I know about SOAP very well but no idea about SSL connection...

please provide some help...

Answer (score 3):

Check out NSURLConnection docs on the apple site: [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

EDIT: added more info.

You need to set up authentication. A quick search of SO produced these results:
[NSURLConnection SSL HTTP Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997673/nsurlconnection-ssl-http-basic-auth) and 
[HTTPS with NSURLConnection - NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578121/https-with-nsurlconnection-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted)

You need to set up your server to handle authentication, then issue a challenge to the device. As you can see in the above posts, there is a function: didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:
You need to use this to handle authentication challenges. You can get a good idea of how to go about it using the above posts.

Your server needs to be set up to handle authentication, as well. I don't know what language you use with your server, but as I use PHP, here is the PHP manual link on authentication:
[PHP authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

It is a tricky thing to do at first, but once you get into it isn't bad (and creating more https connections comes easily). However, writing out everything you would need to do here is a bit much. If you scope out those posts, you can get a general idea about how to go about it. It'll take some working to get it done.

Comment: it means NSURLConnection is itself a secure connection?

Comment: In response to your question, I provided more information above.

Answer (score 2):

Most often this simply means that you have to send data to an HTTPS endpoint. What this also means is that there is a secure connection (done for you automatically) between the client and the server so that the payload (body) of the message is encrypted rather than transmitted in clear text (which is the case with HTTP).

Basically, most times, it is enough just to make sure you're using HTTPS :)

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer

Comment: Same as you would make an HTTP request. Try http://www.google.com and https://www.google.com you'll notice in your browser that the latter is using SSL. Even Google's logo will have a SSL icon next to it.