# What kind of webserver communication techniques are available on iOS 3.2 and higher?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

Maybe there is something better than NSURLConnection for this?

I want to:

- Fetch XML files from web servers
- Either via http or https
- Maybe even with authentification (username, password)
- Post data to an web server

Right now I only know NSURLConnection is my best friend. But maybe there is something even better in the SDK? Just want to make sure. Not complaining about NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSURLConnection is usually your best bet. It's the preferred method to access web resources. Be sure to check out [NSURLConnection SSL HTTP Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997673/nsurlconnection-ssl-http-basic-auth) to see how to use SSL. If your're debugging and your certificate is not quite trusted, check out: [How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert).